# How to get system's filename in Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova, ringtone

I wanna use Ringtone files on my iOS/Android of Cordova.
I used cordova-plugin-native-sound but it's useless.

I wanna use Ringtone sounds via full path.
so I need to get directory's all filename from device root directory.

How can I do? or you know other idea for using device's sounds?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in app.js and get device root path using app.appConfig.filesDir + filename

```
app.appConfig = {       

        filesDir: "",
        filesSubDir: "",
    };

if (device.platform === "iOS") {
     app.appConfig.filesDir = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;          
}
else {
    app.appConfig.filesDir = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;  //for android
}
```

Comment: where is app.js? I use normal cordova (not ionic, not anglarJS). And I use file plugin, output cordova.file.externalRootDirectory. I got URL file:///storage/emulated/0/. but this is not system's root.

Comment: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory is file:///strage/external/0/. I wanna controll file://system/media/audio/ folder for get ringtones list.